# Longitude, latitude to polygon in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, geometry, arcgis-10.4

I'm working in ArcGIS 10.4.1 and trying to write a script (in Python) for making a polygon shapefile from latitude/longitude.

```
txtFile=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
shpOUTpolygon=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
shpOUTpoint=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

en=os.path.dirname(shpOUTpolygon)

env.workspace = en
FCpolygon=os.path.basename(shpOUTpolygon)

FCpoint=os.path.basename(shpOUTpoint)


mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
df=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
dfr=df[0]
sp=dfr.spatialReference

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(en, FCpolygon, "polygon","#","#","#",sp)
cursor =arcpy.da.InsertCursor (FCpolygon, ["SHAPE@"])
array=arcpy.Array()
point=arcpy.Point()
for line in fileinput.input(txtFile):
    point.ID, point.X, point.Y=line.split()
    array.add(point)
polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)
cursor.insertRow([polygon])
fileinput.close()
del cursor
```

For beginning, I test script on XY coordinates. It works fine.
First, I choose some projected coordinate system manually (in Data Frame Properties of Map), then I run my script and created shapefile  is correct.

But when I input longitude and latitude - no errors while script is working, but something wrong with polygon's geometry in output shapefile.

Where should I set a right spatialReference of polygon?

Comment: Never, ever use the `Polygon` constructor without a `SpatialReference` (`spatial_reference` is the second parameter). But your problem is failure to create new Point objects, so the `Array` just has one repeating vertex. The code samples provide the template, and they create new `Point` objects for each loop iteration (it's best practice to close the ring). http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/writing-geometries.htm

Comment: ie, move your `point=arcpy.Point()` line into the `for` loop

Comment: How does your input file looks like, containing lat and lon?

Answer (score 2):

To answer yout question about how to set a spatialReference of a polygon layer:

```
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(path, fc, "POLYGON")
# arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "NAME", "TEXT")
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference("the_name_of_file_of_the_crs")
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(fc, sr)
```

This is, what I use to define the [spatial reference](https://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/arcpy/classes/spatialreference.htm). It takes a name, known by arcgis or a file-path with a .prj extension. Other options are decribed in the documentation linked above.
After that use DefineProjection to store it into the FeatureClass.

- path would be your workspace
- fc is the name of the feature class
- AddField_management is optional

Comment: Andreas Müller, thanks for you answer, but my code contains already a spatial reference of feature class. The question was about spatial reference of polygon.  PolyGeo♦ answered above and my problem is solved, I just can't mark his comment as answer.

Answer (score -1):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342929/longitude-latitude-to-polygon-in-arcpy#comment560146_342929):

> Never, ever use the `Polygon` constructor without a `SpatialReference`
>   (`spatial_reference` is the second parameter). But your problem is
>   failure to create new Point objects, so the `Array` just has one
>   repeating vertex. The code samples provide the template, and they
>   create new `Point` objects for each loop iteration (it's best practice
>   to close the ring).
>   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/writing-geometries.htm

When [you commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342929/longitude-latitude-to-polygon-in-arcpy/350063#comment560636_343138):

> The question was about spatial reference of polygon.  PolyGeo♦
>   answered above and my problem is solved, I just can't mark his comment
>   as answer.

I think you thought a comment by @Vince came from me, but I made no comments on this Q&A.